# How can I install custom voices for pyttsx3 independent of the system the program is running on?

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I'm using pyttsx3 for a project, and I want to use a custom voice that isn't present in the default voices pyttsx3 provide (I figured out how to change voices)

The problem is everywhere I search all I get are problems about not being able to change voices, which isn't the problem here. I have installed the custom voice on my system, yet pyttsx3 doesn't see it. furthermore, I'd like the program to work on other pcs, or in other words, I want the installation of the voice to be a part of the program. Any Help?

If there is another way to use a custom voice that doesn't involve using pyttsx3 I'd be glad to hear about that too, anything would work

Comment: add that in `requirements.txt`

Comment: @Ajay The problem isn't installing the module, it's about how I install the custom voice

Comment: your program is a `GUI` or a webapp?